# Convert QString to text with substitutes for HTML special characters (e.g. tags)

Tags: html, qt, htmlspecialchars, qtextedit, richtext

The user will be able to put in some text into a QLineEdit in a Qt environment. However, these input texts can contain HTML special characters. My aim is to convert this text by replacing all HTML special character occurences with substitutes.

A similar case is found in PHP with the htmlspecialchars() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

The main reason I want to do this is because I want to display the user input in a richtext QTextEdit and I don't want the user to be able to change HTML and I wish to be able to use HTML special characters without too much hassle.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know, is to use `QTextEdit::toHtml`:

```
QString convert();
{
    QString s = lineEdit->text();
    QTextEdit textEdit;
    textEdit.setPlainText(s);
    QString ret = textEdit.toHtml();
    int firstClosingTag = ret.indexOf("</p></body></html>");
    int lastOpeningTag = ret.lastIndexOf(">", firstClosingTag);
    return ret.mid(lastOpeningTag + 1, firstClosingTag - lastOpeningTag - 1);
}
```

There are also two functions, which you could find useful:

[Qt::convertFromPlainText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#convertFromPlainText) and [Qt::escape()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#escape)

Comment: Your solution is not working. The QString still contains tags, while it should replace html special characters, e.g. every < occurence should be replaced with &lt;.

Comment: Ok, I understood the question wrong, here's the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt5, it's **[`QString::toHtmlEscaped`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toHtmlEscaped)**, e.g.:

```
QString a = "Hello, <span class=\"name\">Bear</span>!";
// a will contain: Hello, <span class="name">Bear</span>!

QString b = a.toHtmlEscaped();
// b will contain: Hello, &lt;span class=&quot;name&quot;&gt;Bear&lt;/span&gt;!
```

This is direct equivalent of the [`htmlspecialchars` in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It replaces the  [`Qt::escape`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-obsolete.html#escape) function ([mentioned](/a/16916053) by Amartel), which does the same thing but is now obsolete.

The **[`Qt::convertFromPlainText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-sub-qtgui.html#convertFromPlainText)** function (also mentioned by Amartel) still exists in Qt 5, but it does more than PHP's `htmlspecialchars`. Not only it replaces `<` with `&lt;`, `>` with `&gt;`, `&` with `&amp;`, `"` with `&quot;` but also does additional handling of whitespace characters (space, tab, line feed, etc) to make the generated HTML look visually similarly to the original plain text. Particularly, it may put `<p>…</p>`/`<br>` for linefeeds, non-breaking spaces for spaces and multiple non-breaking spaces for tabs. I.e. this function is not just `htmlspecialchars`, it's even more comprehensive than `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($s))` combination.

**Note** that unlike the PHP's `htmlspecialchars` with `ENT_QUOTES`, none of the Qt functions listed in this answer replace single quote (`'`) with `&apos;`/`&#039;`. So, for example, `QString html = "<img alt='" + s.toHtmlEscaped() + "'>";` won't be safe, only `QString html = "<img alt=\"" + s.toHtmlEscaped() + "\">";` will. (However, as `<` is replaced and `'` has no special meaning outside `<…>`, something like `QString html = "<b>" + s.toHtmlEscaped() + "</b>";` would also be safe.)